# Using arrows on the keyboard, how do I control the location of an image on a background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Given (VS Code):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="image.css">
       <script src="image.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- a <div> section in a document that is styled with CSS: -->
        <!-- canvasContainer can hold a number of child FrameworkElements that 
              works well within a CanvasContentHost -->
        <div id="canvasContainer">
            <!-- the HTML "canvas" element is used to draw graphics, on the 
                   fly, via JavaScript -->
            <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="520"></canvas>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

image.css

```
body{
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-align: center;
    /* px units are used for absolute values, while em is relative 
        to the font size of the particular element */
    #canvasContainer {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 1.250em;
      }
}
```

image.js

```
let Canvas, Context;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => 
    {
        // the 'canvas' element has two attributes, width and height.
        Canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        // use getContext('2d') to get the canvas 2D rendering context
        Context = Canvas.getContext('2d');
        Canvas.width = 600;
        // height will be reset based on aspect ratio
        Canvas.height = 300;
        //---
        let BackgroundImage = new Image();
        BackgroundImage.onload = function () {
            let BackgroundWidth = Canvas.width;
            // naturalWidth equals the density-corrected width of the image in CSS pixels. 
            // naturalHeight equals the density-corrected height of the image in CSS pixels. 
            // calculate the aspect ratio of the image
            let AspectRatio = BackgroundImage.naturalWidth / BackgroundImage.naturalHeight;
            // set canvas height per the aspect ratio
            let BackgroundHeight = Canvas.height = BackgroundWidth / AspectRatio; 
            //---
            // draw background with adjusted width and height
            Context.drawImage(BackgroundImage, 0, 0, BackgroundWidth, BackgroundHeight); 
            //---
            // draw the front image on top of the Background
            let FrontImage = new Image();
            FrontImage.onload = function () {
                let FrontWidth = 40; 
                let FrontHeight = 100; 
                // x and y coordinates of the front image top-left corner                 
                let PositionX = BackgroundWidth / 2 - FrontWidth / 2; 
                let PositionY = BackgroundHeight - FrontHeight; 
                Context.drawImage(FrontImage, PositionX, PositionY, FrontWidth, FrontHeight);
            }
            // replace part of Background with the front image
            FrontImage.src = "Car.jpg"; 
        }
        // background image
        BackgroundImage.src = "Streets.jpg";
    }
)
```

Streets.jpg => https://snipboard.io/4YgDaf.jpg

Car.jpg => https://snipboard.io/ptkWjJ.jpg

This code places a car image on a street image.  It displays correctly.  I want to add code so the car can be moved along the street and make a left hand turn at the intersection.

Using arrows on the keyboard, how do I control the location of the car image on a background street image?

Comment: position the car `absolute` and modify the `top` and `left` style attributes with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen on the `keydown` event, and then run a `render` function on each keypress that will clear the canvas and redraw the images based on the new position.

Of course, this is just a very basic setup to get you started. There is room for a lot of refactoring to improve the structure, readability and performance.

**Reminder:** it's a common naming convention in JavaScript, NOT to use `PascalCase` on variables as these are reserved for defining classes and constructor functions.

```js
const Canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const Context = Canvas.getContext('2d');
const BackgroundImage = new Image();
const BackgroundWidth = Canvas.width;
const FrontImage = new Image();
let FrontWidth = 40; 
let FrontHeight = 100; 
let PositionX; 
let PositionY; 
let BackgroundHeight; 
Canvas.width = 600;
Canvas.height = 300;

function render(){
  Context.clearRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);
  Context.drawImage(BackgroundImage, 0, 0, BackgroundWidth, BackgroundHeight); 
  Context.drawImage(FrontImage, PositionX, PositionY, FrontWidth, FrontHeight);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => 
    {
        BackgroundImage.onload = function () {
            FrontImage.onload = function () {
              const AspectRatio = BackgroundImage.naturalWidth / BackgroundImage.naturalHeight;
              BackgroundHeight = Canvas.height = BackgroundWidth / AspectRatio; 
              PositionX = BackgroundWidth / 2 - FrontWidth / 2; 
              PositionY = BackgroundHeight - FrontHeight; 
              Context.drawImage(BackgroundImage, 0, 0, BackgroundWidth, BackgroundHeight); 
              Context.drawImage(FrontImage, PositionX, PositionY, FrontWidth, FrontHeight);
            }
            FrontImage.src = "https://i.snipboard.io/ptkWjJ.jpg"; 
        }
        BackgroundImage.src = "https://i.snipboard.io/4YgDaf.jpg";
    }
)

const UP    = "ArrowUp";
const DOWN  = "ArrowDown";
const LEFT  = "ArrowLeft";
const RIGHT = "ArrowRight";

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", e =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  if ( e.key === UP ){
    PositionY -= 10;
  }
  if ( e.key === DOWN ){
    PositionY += 10;
  }
  if ( e.key === LEFT ){
    PositionX -= 10;
  }
  if ( e.key === RIGHT ){
    PositionX += 10;
  }
  render();
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="image.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvasContainer">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="520"></canvas>
            </div>
       <script src="image.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I attempt to run this code I get an error message "Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')"

Comment: @ttom I've moved the script right before the ending script tag. Can you try now?

Comment: I placed "Canvas.width = 600;" ... and ... "Canvas.height = 300;" before "const BackgroundWidth = Canvas.width;"  It works correctly now.   --- For some reason, "e.keyCode " has a strike through it.

Comment: I found that the strike through means that "e.keyCode" is deprecated.  An "e.key" should be used instead ... but does not work for this code.

Comment: Yep, you need to find the e.key values for the arrow keys and update the code accordingly. @ttom

Comment: For the keyboard up arrow, I found that e.keyCode equals 38 and e.key equals 'ArrowUp'.  Is this a new standard?

Comment: The MDN page provides all the technical details you need for the Keyboard Event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent (check the Obsolete properties section to find out more about the .keyCode)